# How do I justify homosexuality punishment to a non-muslim?

Tags: sharia, homosexuality

السلام عليكم,

I've had many arguments with non-Muslims about Islam, and they *always* bring up the homosexuality topic and its punishment and view in Islam;  As I'm just a common person with no deep knowledge of Islam, I usually answer them by pointing out that I'm not entitled to justify Allah's motivations.

The issue here is that I have to come up with a purely *logical* reason to convince them that homosexuality is wrong in the modern societies(as they don't believe in Islam, nor god). However, after doing a small research, the only applicable argument I came up with is Ahmad Al Deedat's speach on the topic, although it was I need more convenient reasons and arguments to assist me in proving my point.

Comment: it would be better if you include the answers you recieve, or arguments that you are not able to explain, like what do the arguments from opposition prove, how do they explain it's valid

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about Islam, but about demonstrating homosexuality is wrong to people who won't accept Islamic sources.

Answer (score -2):

Assalamualikum brother,

Here is another question on same issue:

[Why is homosexuality a sin if Allah made me this way?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5686/why-is-homosexuality-a-sin-if-allah-made-me-this-way)

I would like to add some more detail to it, the link below provides lot of details on this issue, hope it will be helpful:

http://www.missionislam.com/knowledge/homosexuality.htm

And here are some of the logical reasons which i personally know of:

- Upbringing of children is duty of male and female couple. When only a man has to take care of child, then he will surely lack everything, which a woman has to give to her. Nature had made man and woman to upbring children as duty of both parents(make and female), but if any one of them is missing,then family will not remain stable
- Homosexuality is NOT genetic, its a choice. if it had been genetic then we wont see a single gay becoming straight, and scientific community to agree that its NOT genetic
- Homosexuals have high level of diseases, just because they do it from behind, which place is dirty and by nature its NOT made for this purpose. So when we go against nature, then we face only destruction. Majority of gays have AIDS as well in world.
- Homosexuals can NEVER enjoy the pleasure of becoming an ACTUAL/Biological father.

More reasons here:

http://www.tfpstudentaction.org/politically-incorrect/homosexuality/10-reasons-why-homosexual-marriage-is-harmful-and-must-be-opposed.html

Comment: Your second and third points are total bunk. AIDS prevalence outside of Africa is not high enough to account for even 1/4 of gay men...and within Africa, sufferers are more likely to be straight than gay.  Promiscuity is the real issue.  Homosexuality happens to be very easy to blame, because it's rife with promiscuity...but the irony is, *that's religion's own fault*.  What do you expect when any trace of a committed homosexual relationship may be evidence of a crime?

Comment: And "it's a choice" is inherently self-defeating. Evidence: Imagine yourself having sex with another man. The very thought probably repulses you on an instinctive, subconscious level, as it does with any straight man -- and even if you fought those instincts and went ahead with it, they would keep you from enjoying it.  Why, then, would *anyone* choose it? How would it even be an option, unless their sexual instincts were differently wired?

Comment: Another aspect of this question would be that whether homosexuality is punishable if practiced by `Non-Muslims` within an Islamic society? Pardon me if the answer to this is obvious, but as a commoner, I understand that Non-Muslims are punished according to their own beliefs for the sins. For example, a Non-Muslim cannot be forced to stop drinking or distribute inheritance by Islamic laws or stop receiving dowry etc. I believe this is relevant to this post because if Non-Muslims are punished base upon their belief then this answers the posted question.

Comment: @cHao, Your point "unless their sexual instincts were differently wired", is described as nafs in Islamic philosophy and it is described as inherently crude (not relatable to humane actions as per normal physiology) behavior of Humans in Islam as well as Christianity and Judaism (I'm talking about Philosophy), Each of the Abrahamic Religion agrees upon restraining (nafs) or instinct (in current context). The thing is that the meaning of word freedom is abstract and it has been taken to it's extremes in history.

Comment: So just saying instinct is responsible, would imply that a human being is just going by the crude behavior, just because he likes it. neglecting the very fact that the behavior is logically defeated according to the natural physiology and evolution and in all the good wisdom on earth is unexplained other than crude behavior

Comment: (Let me add a bit, In psychology a behavior indulges a human when certain things happen in our body, say excitement of trying something new, this may become addicting over a time and will over due course of time creep into the persons lifestyle. Majority of behaviors and including homosexuality, do, may or can follow the same path. All not being good necessarily)

Comment: @xeno, I guess the OP is trying to explain the question in terms of Islamic belief and not it's application to Either muslims or non-muslims, otherwise as you mentioned it is self explained

Comment: @Farhan, it would be great if you would attach sources to your claims, like the one mentioned by 'cHao' in the comment above

Comment: @yawar: google for the claims i made, you will know any sources yourself, i cannot paste all links here

Comment: @Farhan, I agree that after googling, I might find some information, but such can be then said for any information. It is required on all SE sites to give references in order to make the answer hold some authenticity. Since Islam SE is a site for everyone, so thoughtfulness about others reading should be given preference, over ones own personal opinion. not all links even one would suffice

Comment: Infat these days, everyone has their own standards of authenticity

Comment: @yawar: The thing is, if one assumes we were created, then the question of instinct vs conscious choice becomes a big deal. To punish someone for the way they were created is to assume that the creator made a mistake.

Comment: The punishment isn't there for what it is, it is for, even after being told the difference between right and wrong, a person still chooses the wrong. Explanation to suit everyones own personal thought process isn't fit. there are certain pieces of wisdom that not everyone understands, they are too deep in meaning or our personal knowledge falls short to explain it's logic. It is true in all Abrahamic religions including Islam.

Comment: @yawar: It also runs you right smack into an inconsistency also inherent to most if not all of the Abrahamic religions. If there is no compulsion in religion, if we must freely choose to follow that path or not, then humans' punishment of sin (particularly with penalties as severe as death) is a sin in itself.

Comment: @cHao, it is really a misinterpreted or misuded point, quiet common, but not wrong. The thing about there is no compulsion in religion is in relation to muslims who are spreading Islam. If anyone doesn't want to accept that's good and so it is good even if one does accept. Also the thing about punishment is that...

Comment: ..., now (in todays age) although less very less stressed. The fact that Allah considers the intentions of the judge and will be held responsible. The punishment being 'death' (believe me there have been books written on it where it can be kept lenient and where forgiveness is acceptable, and a lot lot more.). It is too serious in Islam jurisprudence when the punishment is death.But, The thing about compulsions isn't applicable here though. I can explain to you from my teeny tiny knowledge this topic, even though I am just another common muslim not a scholar, but it will take me months

Comment: if not years to address all topics and clear all confusions, which will turn into yet another book no one reads