# Why is it haram for two people who truly love each other to get married, even if they have the same gender?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, homosexuality

I'm biologically a girl and I'm attracted to both genders, but mostly girls. I know that as long as I don't act on my feelings, it's not a sin because it's something out of my control.  But how is it fair?

I know that dating someone of the opposite sex is prohibited and I am completely convinced of that, so it doesn't bother me that of course it is the same with dating someone of the same sex. But what about marriage? Why is that haram? Why is it haram that two people who truly love each other to get married?

Please don't reply with that it's against the nature of the world or whatever and that even animals are heterosexuals because no they're not, not all of them.

Homosexuality is in every living thing, human beings, animals and even plants (it's a scientific fact). And also about the diseases that come from same sex intercourse, that happens with straight sex as well, so why isn't it haram?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is ambiguous, you already know the answer that how its wrong. but still asking why its haram? please clarify. Not sure how dating/sex without marriage is Way too different then getting married. because marriage is just a legal bond, you do the same in it, what u do before marriage(like dating love, romance,sex, )

Comment: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5686/why-is-homosexuality-a-sin-if-allah-made-me-this-way

Comment: @anonymous https://islamqa.info/en/38622 and https://islamqa.info/en/search?key=gay

Answer (score 2):

same reason why a man and his mother or sister, who may truly want each other , can not marry. same reason as a Muslim woman can not marry a non-muslim man, even if they truly love each other . In the second case of course , the man could convert to Islam , but in the first case : it is forbidden forever.

So what to do ?

he / she must fight those urges , and will struggle , and Heaven is where the ultimate happiness exist.

yes, life is not fair , but that is the whole idea of us being in a test, isn't it ?

so again, what to do ?

he / she , will seek professional medical help to try to correct this behavior . and he/she will seek help from Allah , by praying and making Duaa . (I advice going to Mekkah and doing Aumra , and ask allah near the Kaaba to heal that physiological illness of being attracted to the same gender )

and Allah is the most Knowing , the most merciful

Answer (score 0):

If marrying the same gender wasn't Haram, we wouldn't be alive. Because everyone would've married the same gender and wwouldn't be able to bring kids so you parents or grandparents would've married the same gender and wouldn't give birth to you. And humans would be extinct :) hope you understand. :D

Comment: Hang on. Are you saying that *everyone* is gay and people only go into opposite-gender relationships because they're forced to? What a sad idea.