# Islam and homosexuality

Tags: homosexuality, jahannam, sexuality

I am a Muslim. I believe in Almighty Allah, the Most Beneficent and Merciful. But I am a lesbian. I've known this since the age of 8. I don't want to go to hell. Will I go to Jahannam? I'm scared. This is who I am. I'm also Non-binary. Help.

Comment: This is neither a clear nor a focused question. All it's doing is attracting opinions and critiques on homosexuality, which is not particularly helpful or productive.

Answer (score 3):

“A person is not to be blamed for his nature. Rather, he is to be blamed if he acts according to his nature.” -Al-Junayd in ‘Hilyat al-Awliya”
THis is from this question: [Why is homosexuality a sin if Allah made me this way?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5686/why-is-homosexuality-a-sin-if-allah-made-me-this-way)

It basically says that you are not going to Hell for the way you are but for the things you would do.

Answer (score 0):

Asslam o Allaikum.

First of all, As another user Yakoub Ali also referred to this:

> **“A person is not to be blamed for his nature. Rather, he is to be blamed if he acts according to his nature.”** - Al-Junayd in Hilyat
> al-Awliya.

This clearly means that although you may seem attracted to the same gender but if you control that feeling of yours and not do anything unlawful / haram then obviously you won't go to Jahannam for this matter.

In other words: One who has homosexual desires is not irresponsible for that but committing unlawful things does make him/her sinful.

Answer (score -1):

If you're a homosexual Muslim with urges to engage in homosexual behavior, then you should simply abstain from it and remain celibate. This is just your test. Just like how if you're a straight Muslim with urges to commit adultery, you shouldn't, and should wait till marriage.